# Add event to a specific jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need `<input id="from" class="date"/>` to have an `onSelect` option. The other date pickers do not.

**Header.php**

```
   <script>
     $(function() {
            $('input.date').each(function() {
                $(this).datepicker();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I need to add the event in a separate script block as it is contained in a different file.
I tried the following but it does not work. 
The input becomes a jQuery Ui datepicker but does not have an event attached.

**one of a number of php pages**

```
 <?php include('header.php'); ?>

   <script>  
     $(function() {
        $('#from').datepicker({onSelect: function() {
            alert(1);
        }
     });
   </script>
```

Is it possible to acheive?

Comment: Are you running both the functions on one page?

Comment: Ultimately, yes, but the code blocks are in separate php files (header which is included in main)

Comment: I was going to suggest using the .not("#from") selector as mccannf states in his answer.  Just separate them for the different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright Guys, Thanks for Helpful answers, Up voted but I did it like this in the end.
Not exactly what I wanted but it will do until I can improve my OO style javascript

**Header.php**

```
<script>
  $(function() {
         $('input.date').each(function() {
           $(this).datepicker({
                    onSelect: function() {
                       typeof dateChanged === 'function' && dateChanged(this);
                    }
              });
         });
     });
 </script>
```

**one of a number of php pages**

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<script>  
    var dateChanged = function(datePicker){
       console.log(datePicker)
     };
</script>
```

**Edit:**

It seems the preferred method would be:

**Header.php**

```
<script>
  $(function() {
         $('input.date').each(function() {
           $(this).datepicker();
         });
     });
 </script>
```

**one of a number of php pages**

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<script>  
    $(function(){
        $('#from').datepicker('option','onSelect',function(){
            alert(1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
   $(function() {
        $('input.date').not("#from").each(function() {
            $(this).datepicker();
        });
    });



   $(function() {
        $('#from').datepicker({onSelect: function() {
        alert(1);
          } 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response, but the problem is the code blocks are in different files, I edited my post to make this clearer

Comment: @andrew - the `not` command should still work though in the first code block. This will ignore the input with id `from`...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just listen to another event, not necessary the custom onSelect.
For instance, listen to the `change` event on the input field, so whenever the data inside changes, you will fire the handed callback.

Edited:
Alright, so if the event won't attach, try to modify the `jquery.ui.datepicker.js` file.
Open it, search for the `function Datepicker()` constructor and then for the `this._defaults` object.

You should change the `onSelect: null, // Define a callback function when a date is selected` with something like

```
onSelect: function(){
    if( /*this is $("#from")*/ )
        alert('1');
},
```

Comment: Hi thanks but the input `onchange` event does not seem to fire when jQuery populates it